# How can we prevent the internet users from seeing aspx page data

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net apsx page which uses a JavaScript function. The code behind function retrieves 1000 rows of data from database, then passes to JavaScript function, which will then display the data on google map. But the problem is: when I view source in IE, I can see the 1000 rows of data. How can I prevent the user from seeing this data?

Comment: by not bringing it back to the browser

Comment: if you send anything to the clients there is no way to prevent from stealing. If you don't want to share your information, don't put it online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot ultimately stop someone from viewing the source code that was sent to them, but you can take steps to make it more difficult.

- Disable right click for browsers that support it (not all do)
- Send the rows down in an encrypted like format such as base64 encoding the data and then using javascript to easily decode it.

There's psychology behind making things harder. Some people will not take the time to defeat your prevention measures as the reward isn't worth the effort, others won't have the skill, and finally others will be curious as to what was worth hiding.

Comment: i am using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript to run the javascript function. Can i use a different way to run the javascript function, so the users will not see the data?

Comment: @user3656901 As has already been explained, the user will always be able to see the data if you send it to them. How you start the function call will make no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't. Once something leaves your site (through web page or REST/SOAP/etc. service call) it's vulnerable. Even if you use SSL to protect data in transit - all the user has to do is get into the browser's development tools and they can view all of your data sent to the browser.

This goes both ways as well. A moderately clever user can mess with data being submitted to your site through a browser. This is why you always do server side validations.